# Why is ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(string, string) is giving me an IOException?

Tags: c#, zip

My code is :

```
private string _filename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location 
    + "\\" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName + ".log";
string ret = _filename;
int index = ret.LastIndexOf(".");
try
{
    if (index > 0)
    {
        ret = ret.Substring(0, index);
    }
    ret = ret + "Zipped.zip";
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filename, ret);
```

This last line gives me a System.IOException. It says the directory name is invalid. Why is _filename an invalid Directory name?

Comment: Because it's a .log file not a directory

Comment: Is it because "appname.log" is file name, not a folder (assuming `_filename` and `filename` is the same variable, which is a bit of a stretch).

Comment: This code does not compile, and you have `filename` and `_filename` used, which are different variables.

Comment: Sorry filename is the property that gets _filename. And Ok I will change the .log and make it a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location is returning a full location (including file) and you are appending another file to the end:

Example:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webapps_testsite\0f5c8994\d5e42433\App_Web_ir4asgqi.dll\ProductName.log

Try this for the _filename:

```
private string _filename = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0,System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName + ".log";
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the ".log" at the end, and it worked just fine.